# How to ask a question properly?

Tags: grammar, questions

Could you help me, please? What is the right option for the following question:

"Why is Google unique?"
"Why Google is unique?"

Thank you very much and wish you a good day!

Comment: Oops, the following might be a better question to use if voting to close as a duplicate: [Why do we say “is it” when asking a question rather than “it is”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/123566/142322)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why Google is unique and want to find out, use "Why is Google unique?"

"Why Google is unique" (your #2 phrase) is a phrase, not a question.

Comment: *Why Google is unique* is a ***noun phrase***, not a statement. Statements are *sentences* (which that isn't), not noun phrases.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for pointing that out! Fixed my answer to fit your suggestion. Perhaps now you'll not dislike it!

Comment: I've retracted my downvote - which is only fair given that you've fixed the "error". But I won't *upvote* because apart from anything else I don't think the question should be here at all (it belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)).